# WordPress is automatically adding "300x200" to media file URL even after setting width to 800px

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website keeps adding 300x200 to the end of my media files when I add them to my pages.

example: https://example.com/wp-content/filename-300x200.jpg

I'm setting the width of the image in the page builder as 800px, but the image resizes to 300 automatically.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

PS: This problem occurs on all users except one (weirdly)

Answer (score 0):

there're several reasons why this is happening on WP
First, navigate to your dashboard>setting>media and check the default size setting for website.
then check your plugins, are there any plugins like wp-smush that resize your media files?
also what is your page builder?
in wp bakery or elementor you can go to setting for the plugin and change the default formatting for media file.
let me know the result

Comment: Hi Mohammad. I checked the settings and found the images were uploading to a medium size of 300, a large size of 1024, and a thumbnail size of 150. Which gives me clarity as to where the 300 size is coming from - but why is it overriding the page builder options. I'm using the fusion builder by Avada.